# How to call different button click event method in if condition?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am beginner of iPhone. I have create five button. button click event perform go to other class in that how to call button click event method..?

it is in ViewController class

```
(IBAction)onclickbutton1
{
}
(IBAction)onclickbutton2
{
}
```

and this `onclickbutton1` and `onclickbutton2` method how to call in other class in if condition
so, that condition of `onclickbutton1` is true perform `onclickbutton` event

Answer (score 1):

Just add a test within the event handling methods:

```
- (IBAction)onclickbutton1
{
    if (conditionIsTrue)
        [OtherClass doThing1];
    else
        [OtherClass doThing2];
}

- (IBAction)onclickbutton2
{
    if (conditionIsTrue)
        [OtherClass doThing1];
    else
        [OtherClass doThing2];
}
```